# dataframes item assignment in databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, azure-databricks

i have created function... i am trying to pass values from a dataframe to a function using following code

```
for row in df.collect():
    var1 = row["col1"]
    var2 = row["col2"]
    var3 = row["col3"]
    var4 = row["col4"]
    var5 = func(var1, var2, var3, var4)
    row["col5"] = var5
```

when i executed above  I am getting following error in databricks

```
TypeError: 'Row' object does not support item assignment
```

how to fix this error, please help me

i tried above code it is not working ..
i want the result of fuction to be stored in dataframe by passing dataframe values

Answer (score 1):

- As the error message clearly indicates, `row['col5'] = var5` is not allowed and hence the error. From the given code, it seems that you are trying to apply a function on each of the row values (for all the rows).

[image]

- Using a similar code, I got the same error:

```
for row in df1.collect():
    var1 = row["c1"]
    var2 = row["c2"]
    var3 = row["c3"]
    var4 = row["c4"]
    #print(var1,var2,var3,var4,row['c5'])
    var5 = concat('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4')
    #print(var5)
    row['c5'] =  var5
```

[image]

- Now, you can instead use the following code if this function is an inbuilt `pyspark.sql.functions`. I am using `concat` function for demonstration.

```
v = concat('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4')
df1.withColumn('c5',v).show()
```

[image]

- If this function does not exist in the `pyspark.sql.functions`, then you can create a Pyspark UDF and use the same method as above in place of `concat()`.

Comment: how to do for var5 = func(var1, var2, var3, var4)

Comment: You do not need that. Since you are trying to update the `col5` in your dataframe by applying `func` on the respective row values. That is what built in pyspark functions or Pyspark UDF does. All you need is the function and withColumn statement as shown in the above image.

Comment: Yes, I want to update col5 by passing var1, var2, var3, var4. sorry i have made mistake in my question i have edited my question please check

Comment: Yes, I get that and it is unnecessary. Check the example I have given. I wanted to concat each of the c1,c2,c3,c4 values for each row to get a new value for c5. Similarly, you can use in built pyspark sql functions or just create a custom function using Pyspark UDF

Comment: i've created function using pyspark udf and executed following code     var5 = func_udf('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4') i getting following error PicklingError: Could not serialize object: RuntimeError: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.